# Paypal IPN/PDT exchange_rate variable is missing in Paypal response

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am having trouble in Paypal response notification.

For some transactions, PayPal doesn't seem to recognise currency conversion. It's not returning any post data regarding exchange rate ($_POST['exchange_rate']) in response notification.

Does this actually exist in PayPal IPN anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

By my interpretation of PayPal's documentation, there will only be a `$_POST['exchange_rate']` field in the IPN results if a currency conversion occurred.  Check the `$_POST['mc_currency']` field in the IPN results, if it's the same as *your* native currency, there won't be a currency conversion, and therefore there won't be a `$_POST['exchange_rate']` field.